# How to use Vim as Python, C, C++, C# IDE

Tags: vim, ide, vi

I am finding it very difficult to use VIM as IDE for programming.
Help me get a solution.

Comment: which aspect do you find "difficult"? you question in the current form is rather arbitrary.

Comment: I want to use vim to write programs and using the built in Command line, I should be able to compile the program and run it.

Comment: Configuring Vim by mapping your own key commands, compiling with patches, adding plugins, tweaking syntax and colorscheme files is trivial (and half the fun!). If you try reading the documentation or one of the countless tutorials, wiki pages, and screencasts that are available, I have no doubt you'll come to a point where you have a functional IDE suited to your needs. At the very least you'll have a clearer question of how to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 3):

generally you can go this path

http://cream.sourceforge.net/

but i would suggest you use more personalized experience and learn some vim commands for your advantage.

For instance you can get few enchancements setting directly in .vimrc

```
set nocompatible        
set backspace=2         
set textwidth=75        
set viminfo='20,\"50    
set history=50          
set mouse=a
set nocp
set ruler
set visualbell
set wildmenu
set noerrorbells
set ignorecase
set incsearch
set vi=%,'50
set vi+=\"100,:100
set vi+=n~/.viminfo

set joinspaces
set showmatch
filetype plugin indent on

filetype on
colorscheme desert
syn on
" source /usr/local/share/vim/vim63/indent.vim
```

if you plan on using python i would recommend set expandtab also.

Then you should head to http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php and get few scripts for you language.

Also you can do keybindings for vim i.e. `set nmap <C-m> :make all<CR>`. (sets ctrl-m to execute command make all)

Answer (score 3):

To answer just the aspects you mentioned:

- 'Building' normally implies, that you have a build system (such as make, scons, cmake, 'solutions', ant, waf, etc.). These build systems are normally started by some command (such as make, scons, cmake + to whatever, devenv, ant, waf). You can launch the build system by setting the `makeprg` option in vim:

  ```
  Program to use for the ":make" command.
  ```

  Set that to whatever your build system needs. You then just use `:make` to trigger the buildsystem. Errors are reported to the buffer containing the list of 'errors'.

  ```
  :help copen
  ```
- 'Running' is just `:!yourbinary.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Vim or neovim both provide async job feature, so you can compile and run c code. To use Vim as c/c++ ide, you can use language server. Just need to install coc.nvim. most of the ide feature has been implemented.

I am author of SpaceVim, which is something like spacemacs but for vim and neovim, if you do not want to config vim/neovim yourself. you can have a try with [SpaceVim](https://spacevim.org).

It provide a `lang#c` layer which support c/c++. and it also has `lang#python` layer. for all the available layers, you can checkout https://spacevim.org/layers/

Here are posts about using SpaceVim as c/c++ ide or python ide:

1. [Use vim as C/C++ IDE](https://spacevim.org/use-vim-as-a-c-cpp-ide/)
2. [Use vim as python IDE](https://spacevim.org/use-vim-as-a-python-ide/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tons of shortcuts already defined in c.vim to make your vim as IDE. Refer this file PDF : ~/.vim/c-support/doc/c-hotkeys.pdf in that plugin. Also refer this
[Tutorial: Make Vim as Your C/C++ IDE Using c.vim Plugin](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/01/tutorial-make-vim-as-your-cc-ide-using-cvim-plugin/) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [eclim](http://eclim.org/) to intagrate Eclipse with vim and run it as a headless server so you can get some of Eclipse functionality.